# How can I style the following elements?

Tags: css

How would I be able to style in CSS these elements(I'm in React?) Thanks in advance.

```
<div className="navbar-social-links">
    <div className="facebook"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFacebook} /></div>
    <div className="instagram"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faInstagram} /></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For **Inline Style**, you can do this.

**CodeSandBox Demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/styling-5i1er

```
<div className="navbar-social-links" style={{background:"green",fontSize:"1rem"}}>
  <div className="facebook"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFacebook} /></div>
    <div className="instagram"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faInstagram} /></div>
 </div>
```

You can also create a seperate CSS file and import into your component using:

```
import "./MyStyle.css";
```

And apply styles in your `MyStyle.css` file like we normally do in CSS.

```
.navbar-social-links{
 // Add CSS properties
}
```

And that should pretty much do it :)

**Note:** Better to avoid inline-styling as you cannot override them easily. You will also have trouble implementing your media queries :)

Comment: Thank you for the help.

Comment: u r welcome. If my answer is helpful, Do accept the answer by clicking on the tick icon next to my answer on the left side.And vote for it. This will help other developers with the same issue. :) thanks and Happy new year

Answer (score 0):

If you working with scss;

1. Install [node-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass)
2. Import your style file `import "./style.scss";`